# how to apply RLE in binary image?

Tags: matlab, compression

Here I have binary image,and I need to compress it using Run-length encoding [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).I used the regular RLE algorithm and using maximum count is 16.

Instead of reducing the file size, it is increasing it. For example 5*5 matrix, 10 values repeating count is one,that is making the file bigger.

How to avoid this glitch?  Is there any better way I can apply RLE partially to the matrix?

Comment: Can you give us the code you are using for RLE?

Comment: From wikipedia: _It is not useful with files that don't have many runs as it could greatly increase the file size_ that's probably the reason, can you also show the image you tried to compress?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for your own usage only you can create your custom image file format, and in the header you can mark if RLE is used or not, and the range of coordinates of X and Y and possible the bit planes for which it is used. But if you want to produce an image file that follows some defined image file format that uses RLE (`.pcx` comes into my mind) you must follow the file format specifications. If I remember correctly, in `.pcx` there wasn't any option to disable RLE partially.

If you are not required to use RLE and you are only looking for an easy to implement compression method, before using any compression, I suggest that you first check how many bytes your 5x5 binary matrix file takes. If the file size is 25 bytes or more, then you are saving it using at least one byte (8 bits) for each element (or alternatively you have a lot of data which is not matrix content). If you don't need to store the size, 5x5 binary matrix takes 25 bits, which is 4 bytes and 1 bit, so practically 5 bytes. I'm quite sure that there's no compression method that is generally useful for files that have size of 5 bytes. If you have matrices of different sizes, you can use eg. unsigned integer 16-bit fields (2 bytes each) for maximum matrix horizontal/vertical size of 65535 or unsigned integer 32-bit fields (4 bytes each) for maximum matrix horizontal/vertical size of 4294967295.

For example 100x100 binary matrix takes 10000 bits, which is 1250 bytes. Add 2 x 2 = 4 bytes for 16-bit size fields or 2 x 4 = 8 bytes for 32-bit size fields. After this, you can plan what would be the best compression method.